# Solaris - Comment Specific Line from File and Add New One

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, solaris

I haven't worked much with solaris, but I'm supposed to be writing a script that searches for a line in a file, comments it out, and writes the correct line below it.

```
for i  in `cat solarishosts`
do
    #print hostname
    echo ${i}

    #get the line number of the expression after the /; save its value to linenum
    linenum="$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 ${i} "awk '/%sugrp ALL=\(user\) lines: /usr/bin/su -, /usr/bin/su - user/a{ print NR; exit }' /usr/local/etc/sudoers")"

    #overwrite the line @ linenum (overwriting just a to add a comment)
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 ${i} "sed -n "${linenum}"p <<< "#%sugrp ALL=\(user\) lines: /usr/bin/su -, /usr/bin/su - user""

    #use the linenum var to make a newlinenum var , this one being one line down from where the commented text was written
    newlinenum=linenum+1

    #write the line in quotes @ the newlinenum position
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 ${i} "sed -n "${newlinenum}"p <<< "%sugrp ALL=\(ALL\) ALL""

done
```

I'm getting weird errors :

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: -c: line 0: `sed -n p <<< #%sugrp ALL=(user) PASSWD: /usr/bin/su -, /usr/bin/su - user'
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `sed -n linenum+1p <<< %sugrp ALL=(ALL) ALL'
```

1. It looks like there's an error with my awk syntax ... but it isn't on line 1? And I'm not sure what the error is
2. I don't have a newline character anywhere in my first sed line?
3. In my code I escaped the "(' it's complaining about

Comment: on solaris, use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` to get much better error messages OR if (you're lucky) the GNU utils are installed, then use `gawk`. After you get your remote line #, you'll have fewer headaches if you combine all your `sed` processing into one remote call. IHMO, this is a medium advanced problem. Arg, also think about how `linenum="$(..."awk ... " .....)"` is being processed by the shell. I don't think you need the outermost dbl-quotes. Good luck.

Comment: YOu need to escape all the slashes in the awk regex.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty messy. You don't need to ssh into the box 3 times. Your quoting is a big problem. And you never actually write the changes back to the file.

Try this: build up the remote command and call ssh once:

```
line='%sugrp ALL=(user) lines: /usr/bin/su -, /usr/bin/su - user'
newline='%sugrp ALL=(ALL) ALL'
file=/usr/local/etc/sudoers

awkcmd='$0 == line {print "#" $0; print new}'
cmd=$(
    printf "awk -v line='%s' -v new='%s' '%s' %s > %s.new && mv %s %s.bak && mv %s.new %s" \
        "$line" \
        "$newline" \
        "$awkcmd" \
        "$file" "$file" "$file" "$file" "$file" "$file"
)

while read -r host; do
    echo "$host"
    # perform the remote command
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 "$host" sh -c "$cmd"

done < solarishosts
```

I use single quotes as much as possible to reduce the need for backslashes in the constant strings, and all variables are quoted when used.